# Build CRUD view as CakePHP in javascript framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, cakephp, model-view-controller, npm

In Cake PHP, we can easily build CRUD view as follow

bin/cake bake all users

building users table for CRUD operation.

At which Javascript framework can do simply like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good the most similar to what you are looking for is some generators of yeoman projects that through console you general code depending on the framwork you use.

http://yeoman.io/generators/

example I use this, but just side client, in console with angular:

https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack